# When do we do typecast in #define

Tags: c, casting, macros

When do we use a typecasting in definitions like this:

```
#define MAGIC_NUMBER  (unsigned char)0x5D
```

And why is it necessary?

Comment: `#define` is a simple text replacement. Whatever you do in a `#define`, it is because of how you intend to use that macro later.  So this question cannot really be answered except by the tautology "Because you want the macro to give an `unsigned char`"

Answer (score 6, accepted):

To answer

> *why is it necessary*

without the explicit cast, `0x5D` is considered as integer literal or integer constant, in hexadecimal form. With the cast, we try to *explicitly* make the representation of it as an `unsigned char`.

> *When do we use*

is too broad and probably out of scope for an answer. One *possible* scenario, for example, is while supplying the MACRO as the argument to a `%hhx` format specifier, in case of `printf()` family.

Comment: Does it affect program size in case of embedded programming ?